# IllegalArgumentException when print out triangle

Tags: java

I want to print out:

```
 ____*
 ___*_*
 __*___*
 _*_____*
 *********
```

(underline "_" is substituted by space " ")

So here are the codes:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    triangle(5);
 }

public static void triangle(int height){
String space = " ";
String asterisk = "*";

if(height == 1){
    System.out.println(asterisk);
}else{
    //print out the "height - 1" line of triangle
    for (int i = 1; i <= height - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(space.repeat(height - i) + asterisk + space.repeat(2 * i - 3) + asterisk);
    }
    System.out.println(asterisk.repeat(2 * height - 1));
}
```

}

And click "run", it is said on the console that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: count is negative: -1
  at java.base/java.lang.String.repeat(String.java:3565)
  at comp1110.lab2.Triangle.triangle(Triangle.java:16)
  at comp1110.lab2.Triangle.main(Triangle.java:47)
```

So what's the issue?

Comment: `2 * i - 3` is negative when `i` is one.

Comment: Seems like you'd want a special case for the top line, since it only has one asterisk.  Currently attempting to have -1 spaces between two asterisks isn't doing the trick.

Comment: I posted an answer with a hint on how to derive the correct formula for the padding. Since this is obviously a homework, I will not be doing you any favors if you don't try to figure it out yourself based on my hints. I can post the answer later on if you can't come up with the answer. On a side note, this is an important lesson in problem decomposition. You are trying to solve everything at once, instead of thinking of the different sub-problems in the exercise and try to solve each one independently.

Comment: @CarterZhang did any of this help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `triangle()` method, inside the for loop. Let's analyze the error code: `space.repeat(2 * i - 3)`. On the very first time the for loop is running, `i` = 1.

2 times i = 2. 2 minus 3 = -1. The result is a negative number. That's why you have the count is `negative -1 error`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.... One, @ublec already mentioned. Your first loop fails because your math is wrong. The other is that you're trying to solve everything at once instead of breaking this problem into smaller problems (problem decomposition). When you do that, you find the solution for each part, and then synthetize the overall solution by summing all the parts.

Let's decompose the problem. You first have the problem of the spacing for the first half of the triangle:

```
1   *
2  *
3 *
4*
```

The whitespace leading the asterisk is one minus the height. So, for a height of 5, your top layer has 4 spaces then an asterisk, then 3 plus the asterisk and so forth. You should handle that part in it's on `System.out.print()` statement (not `println`).  Now that you have that, you need to "paint" the second half of the triangle.

The top layer can simply print a line feed. HOWEVER, for subsequent levels, the spacing is 1, 3, 5, 7, etc...

```
1    *
2   *1*
3  *-3-*
4 *--5--*
5*---7---*
```

Do you see the pattern now? Your formula to calculate the padding between asterisks is obviously wrong. `String#repeat(int)` will not work to pad area between asterisks unless you find the correct correlation between `i` and the number of spaces between asterisks. Do you see the fact that there is an equal amount of dashes to the left and right of the number I placed in between the asterisks to indicate the total amount of spaces per layer? That's a hint of how you should proceed.

Lastly, your last print out statement is correct.

I ran your code with the modifications I suggested, and this is my output for a triangle of height 5:

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
*********
```